# cuda / nvidia-driver mismatch on sagemaker with custom container

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, nvidia-docker

I have a custom container (derived from `nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime`) to run trainings on sagemaker. But on startup i'm getting the error `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:32` which apparently wants to tell that my cuda version doesnt support the graphics driver (...how nice would it be to expose both version numbers along with the error message...), but i cannot figure out how to find out what display driver is mounted in the container. All i can find is that it says that sagemaker has nvidia-docker buildin. I tried to fire `nvidia-smi` before the error occures, but that command isnt known in the container. There is a mysterious sentence

```
"If you plan to use GPU devices for model inferences (by specifying 
GPU-based ML compute instances in your CreateEndpointConfig request),
make sure that your containers are nvidia-docker compatible."
```

I'm pretty sure that this is the case, but there is no checkbox or whatever to toggle "run this container with host GPU access". Any ideas how i can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Found the problem, i had choosen `ml.m4.xlarge` as instance type, apparently those dont have a GPU / are not sharing it. Switching to `ml.p2.xlarge` solved the problem.

Comment: Indeed. M4/M5/C5 are only CPU. For GPU use P2/P3.
Full list: https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/instance-types/

Comment: is cuda driver version specific to the aws instance or is it the same across all GPU enabled instances? if the choice of instance changes in future, would the same custom container still run without any issues?